# Get a list of files (in the way similar to `ls`) on website/webpage before choosing which to download

Tags: files, ls, download, web

Let's say I'm on a webpage on which there are several hyperlinks to pdf documents. I want to download those pdf. Is there a way to get a list of those documents (in the `ls` way) which then allows to choose better which file to download with `wget` or `curl`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `lynx` or `links` (text mode web browsers) to download and display a list of links in a web page, then pipe that into `grep` to extract only the PDF links.  For example:

```
URL='https://www.example.com/files/'
lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "$URL" | grep -i '\.pdf$'
```

NOTE: it is important to double-quote `"$URL"`, especially if the URL contains spaces or shell metacharacters (such as `;` or `&`, which are very frequently seen in URLs).  Save yourself a headache and **always** quote URL strings and variables containing URLs when you use them (in fact, it's pretty nearly always a good idea to double-quote variables when you use them, whether they contain URLs or not - see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)).

You could then redirect `grep`'s output to a file, edit it with a text editor to delete the PDF files you're not interested in, and then use `wget`'s `-i` (`--input-file=file`) option to download all the URLs in the file.   Or you could manually download them one at a time with `wget` or `curl`.

---

BTW, `wget` also has a `-m` (`--mirror`) option for mirroring web sites, and numerous options for controlling exactly what gets downloaded (e.g. `-A` and `-R` to accept or reject files matching suffixes or certain glob-like patterns - `-A pdf` or `-A '*.pdf'` - and `--accept-regex` & `--reject-regex` to do the same with regular expressions), and to control whether wget will follow links to other sites (and to **which** other sites), whether to follow links to parent or child directories (and how many levels deep), and more.   There are a lot of options, and even more interactions between combinations of options, so don't expect to master it instantly.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @cas. It works good and therefore I upvoted the question. Another answer below seems to work also well and therefore I cannot accept either as I think there are equally good

Comment: Accept the one you like best.  Or wait for a better answer to come along.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify what webpage you're referring to but if it provides
listing of files such as https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar you can use lftp:

```
$ lftp https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/
cd ok, cwd=/gnu/tar
lftp ftp.gnu.org:/gnu/tar> ls
(...)
-rw-r--r--          181  2021-02-13 06:32  tar-latest.tar.bz2.sig
-rw-r--r--   4.2M&nbsp;  2021-02-13 06:32  tar-latest.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--          181  2021-02-13 06:32  tar-latest.tar.gz.sig
-rw-r--r--   2.1M&nbsp;  2021-02-13 06:33  tar-latest.tar.xz
-rw-r--r--          181  2021-02-13 06:33  tar-latest.tar.xz.sig
```

You can now create a directory on your local filesystem, change to it
and download a file:

```
lftp ftp.gnu.org:/gnu/tar> !mkdir /tmp/download
lftp ftp.gnu.org:/gnu/tar> lcd /tmp/download
lcd ok, local cwd=/tmp/download
lftp ftp.gnu.org:/gnu/tar> get tar-latest.tar.xz
2022-01-02 14:54:21 https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-latest.tar.xz -> /tmp/download/tar-latest.tar.xz 0-2226068 1.72 MiB/s
2226068 bytes transferred in 1 second (1.72 MiB/s)
```

Or multiple files using `mget` command.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @ArkadiuszDrabczyk. It works good and therefore I upvoted the question. Another answer seems to work also well and therefore I cannot accept either as I think there are equally good

Answer (score 1):

Open the developer console in your browser with Ctrl+Shift+I and go to the Console tab. Then paste this code and press Enter:

```
let allLinks = ""
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(item => {
  if(item.href.endsWith("pdf")){
    allLinks += item.href + "\n"
  }
})
console.log(allLinks)
```

This will list all the pdf links in the console, which you can then copy to a text editor and further edit.